# How the Instagram app displaying their profile in grid view, implemented it with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, instagram

How the instagram displaying their grid view in profile. looks like each card not waiting each other and displaying which card has done to load.

is there anyone has implemented something like this. and maybe you can sharing to use how to do something like that.

Thank's for help

Example what i have done. my goals is display each card in profile like instagram. not waiting hole of list loaded.

[image]

Example of instagram which is my goals. if we see, the instagram like displaying it like a stream to each card

[image]

Comment: Hi There. This is more of an opinion based question and as such not suitable here. Post more info as to what you have tried so far and where exactly are you stuck ?

Comment: i have a list of product will display it into the grid view. but the problem is we need to load that hole of array/list from server example limit 15. than i got the loading there, and when that list is loaded .display all of it in grid view for now its appear like boom change the loading and display the grid view of produk.

Comment: if see the instagram profile. they have a really cool way how to display list of profile picture in grid view. is like each of their card of picture has a stream to display the picture. not waiting each other just card place holder then when stream done (maybe) the picture displayed

Comment: updated the question description

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, int) {
        return Divider(color: Colors.black,);
      },
     // shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: 2.0,
          children: List.generate(6, (index) {
            return Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                child: Text(
                  'item no : $index',
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        );
      },
      itemCount: 4,
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code or add comments to understand the code?

Comment: is possible to use this with sliver list ?

Comment: updated the question description